# Java Spark insert JSON into table data type mismatch

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

I am inserting my JSON into Hive in the following way:

```
Dataset<Row> jsonData = spark.read().json("file:///root/jsonData.json");

//In reality this table has more columns, I made it shorter for the sake of readability    
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE table1 ( \n" +
            "`test_name` string, \n" +
            "`test_timestamp` timestamp, \n" +
            "`test_id` string");

jsonData.write().insertInto(table1);
```

Once I execute this I get the following Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CAST(`test_name` AS test_id)' due to data type mismatch.

My guess is that this problem occurs because the entities in my JSON has a different order than the order of the columns that I create as shown below.

Previously I was doing like this:

```
Dataset<Row> jsonData = spark.read().json("file:///root/jsonData.json");
jsonData.createOrReplaceTempView("jsonDataTable");
Dataset<Row> showAll = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM jsonDataTable");

//Save as table jsonDataTable with overwrite 
showAll.write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("jsonDataTable");
showAll.show();
```

The solution below is very nice since it automatically create a table from my JSON, the problem with it is that it sets all COLUMN TYPE as string, struct or array but in some cases I want to specify timestamp etc.

I would need help to somehow create a table first and then insert the JSON where the order does't matter (can't it not match somehow? test_name -> goes to test_name etc?).

Other suggestions are very welcome - the intention is to create a table where I specify COLUMN TYPE and insert JSON data.

Comment: @cricket_007 tagging you here, I bet you know a elegant simple solution to my problem.

Comment: Sample data????

Comment: @Bala Fully valid and verified JSON containing nothing special really. The data is not the problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below (in pyspark) should give you ideas. I have used Spark 1.6

data4.json

```
{"name":"Spark","id":"10"}
{"name":"Hive","id":"5"}
```

Load json and see that both columns are string

```
>>> sqlContext.read.json("data4.json").printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

>>> sqlContext.read.json("data4.json").show()
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
| 10|Spark|
|  5| Hive|
+---+-----+
```

Change column `id` datatype to `long` and save to table `t3`

```
>>> sqlContext.read.json("data4.json").withColumn("id", col("id").cast("long")).saveAsTable("t3")

>>> sqlContext.read.table("t3").printSchema()                                   
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```